# How do I programmatically set the current page of a kentico unigrid?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, kentico

I want a custom page state mechanism for a series of pages that have a Kentico (v7.0.4990.22818) UniGrid control on them. The default state for the UniGrid does not work because we build up the grid data bind query based on the state of radio buttons so a custom approach is needed.

I want to be able to programmatically select the current page from the code behind. I tried exploring the properties of the UniGrid to work out how I could do this but setting the UniPage.CurrentPage property doesn't work. So first step was to disable the default state for the grid i.e.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid.RememberState = false;
}
```

Then in the page_load event I attempt to set the UniGrid current page property

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid.Pager.UniPager.CurrentPage = ListStateManager.CurrentPage;
}
```

But when the UniGrid control loads, the value set is lost and the grid only ever loads the first page.

Is there an approach that would allow me to set the current page for the grid?

**Update**

The first access to the pager property of unigrid.ascx has the expected CurrentPage value and has a callstack like this:

> App_Web_jce5qutr.dll!CMSAdminControls_UI_UniGrid_UniGrid.Pager.get() Line 118   C#
>       App_Web_jce5qutr.dll!CMSAdminControls_UI_UniGrid_UniGrid.SetPager() Line 2431 + 0x17 bytes  C#
>       App_Web_jce5qutr.dll!CMSAdminControls_UI_UniGrid_UniGrid.UniGridView_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 891 + 0xa bytes  C#
>       [External Code] 
>       App_Web_25xa3r10.dll!CMSModules_ManageTerritories_Default.BindGrid() Line 147 + 0x31 bytes  C#
>       App_Web_25xa3r10.dll!CMSModules_ManageTerritories_Default.Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 58 + 0xd bytes  C#
>       [External Code] 
>       App_Code.dll!SCCommon.StatefulListPage.OnLoad(System.EventArgs e) Line 64 + 0xf bytes   C#
>       [External Code]

Then the pager property is called multiple times (around 15 times) and the CurrentPage property has been reset to a value of 1 with the call stack like this:

> App_Web_jce5qutr.dll!CMSAdminControls_UI_UniGrid_UniGrid.Pager.get() Line 118   C#
>       App_Web_jce5qutr.dll!CMSAdminControls_UI_UniGrid_UniGrid.SetPager() Line 2431 + 0x17 bytes  C#
>       App_Web_jce5qutr.dll!CMSAdminControls_UI_UniGrid_UniGrid.Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 256 + 0xd bytes  C#
>       [External Code]

Answer (score 0):

If I set

```
<cms:UniGrid ID="gridElem" runat="server" RememberState="False" ...>
```

in markup and e.g.

```
gridElem.Pager.UniPager.CurrentPage = 2;
```

in Page_Load in code behind, it works perfectly well for me.

Try to debug Pager property of the UniGrid.ascx.cs to see when it's being accessed. And also put a breakpoint on the line where you are setting the CurrentPage property to see what happens first.

Comment: Two calls made to the Pager property get accessor, first time occurs when I call Grid.DataBind() and the CurrentPage value is correct. Then second call is from "External Code" -> Page_Load and on this access the CurrentPage value has reset to 1 :( - the get accessor is then repeatedly being called (around 15 times) from "External Code"